# Exif file don't find latitude and longitude android

Tags: android

I have tryed to find the coordination of a my photo on my internal storage but when i start my app in my textfield there aren't a return of the latidude or longitude but if i select the witdht or height there is a return.
There is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView imageView;
DBOpenHelper doh = new DBOpenHelper(this);
private TextView textFieldLat;
private TextView textFieldLong;
String imagefile ="/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20160712_172931.jpg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Button takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);

    textFieldLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFieldLat);
    textFieldLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFieldLong);

    textFieldLat.setText(ReadExifLat(imagefile));
    textFieldLong.setText(ReadExifLong(imagefile));
}

String ReadExifLat(String file){
    String exif=file;
    try {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file);
        exif = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return exif;
}

String ReadExifLong(String file){
    String exif=file;
    try {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file);
        exif = exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return exif;
}
}
```

if i replace the TAG_GPS_LATITUDE with TAG_GPS_WIDTH it works.
The photo in my device have the coordinate.
Thanks

Comment: exif=e.getMessage();. Put that in the catch blocks.

Comment: `there aren't a return of the latidude or longitude`. Then what is returned instead?